# Excel dates are not in Date format

Tags: excel, excel-dates

I have extracted data from a SAP application and now I want to uses this data on excel sheet and perform certain action. However, data is time series data and dates are not in dates format.

I see `01/9/2009` in Excel sheet but when I double click that cell the date appears as '01/9/2009`. I even tried pasting as values but in that case it reads it as day/Month/Year instead of Month/Day/year.

Please help me out on this. I have lot of data so cannot do manually.

Comment: How do you export data from SAP? Do you do this from ALV or itab? In what format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these dates are in a column, select it, Text to Columns, Tab delimited and at Step 3 of 3 select Date: and `MDY`.